# How to return all documents for each bucket after ElasticSearch term aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I use the following simple query to search across documents in my Elastic index:

```
{
    "query": { "query_string": { "query": "*test*" } },
    "aggregations": {
        "myaggregation": {
            "terms": { "field": "myField.raw", "size": 0 }
        }
    }
}
```

This returns me the number of documents per distinct value of `myField.raw`.

Since I'm interested into *all* actual documents than the total number, I tried to add the following `top_hits` sub aggregation:

```
{
    "query": { "query_string": { "query": "*test*" } },
    "aggregations": {
        "myaggregation": {
            "terms": { "field": "myField.raw", "size": 0 },
            "aggregations": {
                "hits": {
                    "top_hits": { "size": 2000000 }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This ugly usage of `top_hits` works, but is slow as hell.

Is there any proper way to fetch the actual documents for each bucket after doing the `term` aggregation?

Comment: No, no other way. And aggregations are not meant to return all documents. Also, no use case is ok if it wants to return all documents in Elasticsearch. It would a very memory intensive operations and, also, slow.

Comment: too bad. i used the terms aggregation now without any subaggregation and build up my specific result in the client. thanks anyway! :)

Comment: supposing I can wait for `top_hits`, but it returns 100 hits per bucket, and i have 1 million buckets. Suppose also my `size + from` limit is the default 10000, then can I get all the hits for all the buckets?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using `collapse` on `field`?

It returns doc grouped under inner_hits (`hits.hits[].inner_hits.<collapse-group-name>.hits.hits[]._source`)

Refer - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-collapse.html