# ElasticSearch: retriving documents belonging to buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve documents for the past year, bucketed into 1 month wide buckets each. I will take the documents for each 1 month bucket, and then further analyze them (out of scope of my problem here). From the description, it seems "Bucket Aggregation" is the way to go, but in the "bucket" response, I am getting only the count of documents in each bucket, and not the raw documents itself. What am I missing?

GET command

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "DateHistogram" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "timestamp",
                "interval": "month"
            }
        }
    }, 
    "size" : 0
}
```

Resulting Output

```
{
  "took" : 138,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1313058,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "DateHistogram" : {
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key_as_string" : "2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1422748800000,
        "doc_count" : 270
      }, {
        "key_as_string" : "2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1425168000000,
        "doc_count" : 459
      }, 
      (...and all the other months...)
      {
        "key_as_string" : "2016-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1456790400000,
        "doc_count" : 136009
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, you simply need to add the a [`top_hits` sub-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) in order to retrieve some documents for each bucket:

```
POST /your_index/_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "DateHistogram" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "timestamp",
                "interval": "month"
            },
            "aggs": {                  <--- add this
                "docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    "size" : 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks Val. Since i am expecting around 30 documents per bucket, this method is convenient. I initially got discouraged looking at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030049/how-to-return-all-documents-for-each-bucket-after-elasticsearch-term-aggregation But looks like the top_hits does my job.

Comment: so what if you're expecting 30 hits per bucket, and about 10 million buckets? can you scroll somehow?

Comment: No, paginating through buckets is not yet possible [but might eventually be implemented](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915)